# Basic introduction to mixed effect models?

Tags: mixed-model, references

I have noticed in this year how mixed effects models have inundated ecological literature. To be honest I just learned about them a year ago, and I have not found a basic approach to them. Can anyone recommend the most basic paper that explains them, or a website or video?

Comment: Don't know whether they're basic enough but you might look at Bolker et al. *Trends in ecology & evolution* 24:127-135 or Bolker chapter 13 in Fox et al *Ecological Statistics: Contemporary Theory and Application* Oxford University Press 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I like this:](http://www.bodowinter.com/resources.html)  by Bodo Winter. It uses R for the example models.